# Simon Haykin book question

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

Currently in the book on p. 19 (Neural Networks and Learning Machines
Third Edition) I see:

Using the binomial expansion for $(1 - wz^{-1})^{-1}$ , we may rewrite it as $\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}w^{l}z^{-l}$. How Simon did that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose, that [progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression) is connected to this rewriting. Hence, first formula is just the sum of an infinite decreasing geometric progression with $1$ as $b_{1}$ and $wz^{-1}$ as q.

Comment: I think so too, but why he needs "binomial expansion" here?!

Comment: okay, i'm not sure i did quite understand your question was.

Comment: maybe it's just expression to show a way of thinking.

Comment: You are correctly understood my question.